# Tem como criar um "Modo Reader" com PHP?

Tags: php

No Safari tem um "Modo Reader" que remove tudo, de um site e deixa só o artigo.

Alguém sabe de uma biblioteca de código aberto que fornece a mesma funcionalidade? Ou, é difícil de implementar?

Preciso desenvolver isso em PHP.

Exemplo no Iphone: [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Talvez essa pergunta possa te ajudar.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17733275/php-how-to-get-main-html-content-like-reader-mode-in-firefox

Comment: Obrigado, era isso mesmo!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Carlos,

1) Crie o arquivo [Readability.php](http://code.fivefilters.org/php-readability/src/5112edb387b53931ab9324b890fa581c0e951d2d/Readability.php?at=master)

2) Crie o arquivo [JSLikeHTMLElement.php](http://code.fivefilters.org/php-readability/src/5112edb387b53931ab9324b890fa581c0e951d2d/JSLikeHTMLElement.php?at=master)

3) Crie o arquivo index.php com [este código](http://pastebin.com/RZQ6Q0Ca):

No trecho

> $url = 'http://';

Adicione o endereço do site.

Retirado de : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17733275/php-how-to-get-main-html-content-like-reader-mode-in-firefox